# How does one properly define "quot" as a single function?

Tags: haskell

As an example, I'm trying to define quot in a single function.  I'm struggling to see how to do so without appending an extra parameter (in this case, a counter).

```
quot x y n
  | x < y = n
  | otherwise = quot (x-y) y (n+1)

quot0 x y = x y 0
```

I've run into this problem multiple times and continue to use this ad hoc solution, while I know there must be an easy way to incorporate the n implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You use a local binding, either with `where`

```
myQuot :: Int -> Int -> Int
myQuot x y = go x 0
  where
    go x n 
       | x < y     = n
       | otherwise = go (x - y) (n + 1)
```

or `let … in …`:

```
myQuot2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
myQuot2 x y = 
  let 
    go x n 
       | x < y     = n
       | otherwise = go (x - y) (n + 1)
  in go x y 0
```

Alternatively, you provide both functions but write an easy to use wrapper for your users:

```
myQuotImp x y n = if x < y then n else myQuout (x - y) y (n + 1)

myQout3 :: Int -> Int -> Int
myQout3 x y = myQuotImp x y 0
```

Comment: Another pedantic point..is there any way to substitute d into myQuot without the extra where? apologies as I don't know if there's a way to do a multiline comment here     `myQuot :: Int -> Int -> Int
    myQuot x y = go x 0
      where
        go x n
           | d < 0 = n
           | otherwise = go d (n + 1)
           where d = x - y`

Comment: @WarrickMacmillan, you can do it using `fix` from `Data.Function`, but it doesn't tend to improve clarity.

Comment: @WarrickMacmillan By the way, there is no way to do multiline comments. To post such things in comments as valid Haskell, you might use explicit braces and semicolons: `myQuot :: Int -> Int -> Int; myQuot x y = go x 0 where { go x n | d < 0 = n | otherwise = go d (n + 1) where { d = x - y } }`

Answer (score 4):

```
quot x y | x < y = 0
         | otherwise = 1 + quot (x-y) y
```